# how to change the dist-folder path without overwriting existing files in output folder

Tags: java, angular, google-app-engine, angular-cli

I'm using JAVA and app engine as backend and angular as frontend also I want to directly build my files using `ng build` and output them to my java project so I tried replacing `outputPath` in my `angular.json` file as so

{

```
  ...
  "options": [
    {
      "outputPath": "../../myproject/java/src/main/webapp/",
      ...
    }
  ],
  ...
}
```

all files are correctly placed in `webapp` folder but the only problem is that it overwrites the whole folder leading to loosing other project files/directories, so I have to manually place files into this directory which is what I want to avoid.

I also tried changing the `base-href`and try to load my files from a `/dist` folder.But changing `base-href` leads to incorrect url routing.

any solution to avoid overwriting files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are manually adding files after build, then you can try writing a `postbuild` action that copies all those files into build folder.

File `package.json`:

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build --prod",
    "postbuild": "cp somefile ../../myproject/java/src/main/webapp/somefile",
    ...
  },
```

If you are on windows OS and want to do multiple actions, you may use `powershell` script that can be invoked as a `postbuild` step.

```
  "scripts": {
    ...
    "postbuild": "powershell ./update-build-folder.ps1",
    ...
  },
```

Everytime you run `npm build`/`yarn build`, build directory will be cleaned, afterwards angular CLI will output the JS files and then all those custom files will be placed in the build directory.

Comment: Thanks it worked do you have a solution using the `ng` command?

Comment: Angular CLI doesn't provide any post build action unless we create a custom CLI builder which would be much more work!

Answer (score 0):

What version of angular-cli are you using? I'm able to successfully build to a directory that is outside of the angular project, which contains other files, WITHOUT those additional files getting deleted. (this is with angular-cli v7.3.9)

Lastly, are you sure that some OTHER script isn't the one deleting the files in your build path? (i.e. a backend build script)

```
...
"options": {
            "outputPath": "../custom-output/web/build-here",
            ...
},
...
```

Screenshots:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Doesn't Angular CLI [delete the output directory](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/8ffb755ef084d358638045dd58e2f5f0297139a1/packages/angular_devkit/build_angular/src/utils/delete-output-dir.ts) before building again?

Comment: In the example I posted, only `../custom-output/web/build-here/` directory is impacted (all build files are placed in this directory).

The other files that exist in the directories leading to the build directory are unaffected: `../custom-output/web/another-file.txt` and `../custom-output/some-file.txt`.

Comment: @christian hello. I think you've misunderstood my question. My question was how to redirect builded files to a folder that already contains files not in a specific folder